# Is there a need to get nice Tefilin?

Tags: tefilin, mitzvah, maseches-shabbos

[Mesechtas Shabbos 133b](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2119.htm) gives a list of items that one should do with nice things in order to beautify the Mitzva. Conspicuously absent is Tefilin. Is there a source to get nice Tefilin? If not, why is Tefilin excluded?

> דתניא זה אלי ואנוהו התנאה לפניו במצות עשה לפניו סוכה נאה ולולב נאה
>   ושופר נאה ציצית נאה ספר תורה נאה וכתוב בו לשמו בדיו נאה בקולמוס נאה
>   בלבלר אומן וכורכו בשיראין נאין

Comment: I don't think Tefilin are "[c]onspicuously absent;" mezuzah, animals for korbanos, and matzah aren't mentioned either, and neither are many other חפצא של מצוה. Why do you think Tefilin should *need* to be on this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Magen Avos from the Rashbatz on Pirkei Avos 2:1 brings this list and explains that it is the same point as Rabi Yehuda is making there, by doing the mitzvos on a level of נאה, it will be for him a תפארת לפני קונו, a praise before his Creator, ובני אדם גם כן יפארוהו, and people will also praise him.

Taking this into concideration I would suggest Tephilin don't need to be on this list as we find them already called a פאר in various sugyos, see for instance Brachos 11a. It would therefore be simple that they are performed on this level of נאה, in order to be a פאר.